# Table in beamer empty for many slides when using \only with incremental specifications

Tags: tables, beamer, overlays

I want to have a table which is empty on the first slide and then successively reveals each cell of each row. I like to use incremental specifications such as `\only<+->{Row Text}` so that I can easily adjust the order of the content. However, filling a table with such overlays seems to produce a series of empty slides equal to the number of overlays plus one when only one is necessary. Where are these extra slides coming from?

Here's an (almost) minimal working example, with the first frame using the incremental specifications and the second not doing so, to show the contrast.

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext,12pt,t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{With incremental specifications}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\setlength{\tymax}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\small
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}LL@{}} \toprule
Column 1&Column 1\\
\midrule
\only<+->{\textcolor{blue}{Row Text}}&\only<+->{\textcolor{blue}{Row Text}}\\
\only<+->{\textcolor{blue}{Row Text}}&\only<+->{\textcolor{blue}{Row Text}}\\
\only<+->{\textcolor{blue}{Row Text}}&\\

\bottomrule

\end{tabulary}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Without incremental specifications}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\setlength{\tymax}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\small
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}LL@{}} \toprule
Column 1&Column 1\\
\midrule
\only<2->{\textcolor{blue}{Row Text}}&\only<3->{\textcolor{blue}{Row Text}}\\
\only<4->{\textcolor{blue}{Row Text}}&\only<5->{\textcolor{blue}{Row Text}}\\
\only<6->{\textcolor{blue}{Row Text}}&\\

\bottomrule

\end{tabulary}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems to be related to `tabulary`, if you replace it with `tabular` or `tabularx` it works fine.

Comment: "Where are these extra slides coming from?" tabulary processes the content multiple times to figure out the necessary space etc.